# Django ORM - Primary key not available after save while using UUIDField and RandomUUID In Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-postgresql

For a project I'm working on, in one of the models i am using `models.UUIDField` for primary key with the default value set to `django.contrib.postgres.functions.RandomUUID`

Here's my model.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.functions import RandomUUID
from django.db.models import JSONField


class NewsItem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID)
    title = models.ForeignKey(RichText, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+',
                              null=True)
    subtitle = models.ForeignKey(RichText, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+',
                                 null=True)
    excerpt = models.ForeignKey(RichText, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+',
                                null=True)
    text = models.ForeignKey(RichText, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+',
                             null=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(ImageObject, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+',
                              null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    frequency = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=1)
    text_effects = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, default=dict)
    scroll_speed = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=1)
    scroll_direction = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'news_items'
```

The issue here is that i need to immediately access the primary key after the object has been inserted into the database, however trying to access `pk` or `id` after calling `save` simply returns a literal string `RandomUUID()`

```
In [1]: from media.models import NewsItem

In [2]: n = NewsItem()

In [3]: n.save()

In [4]: n.id
Out[4]: RandomUUID()

In [5]: str(n.id)
Out[5]: 'RandomUUID()'
```

However, if i issue a query like `model.objects.first()` or `model.objects.last()` and then access the `id` or `pk` of the returned instance, it works as expected.

```
In [6]: from media.models import NewsItem

In [7]: n = NewsItem.objects.first()

In [8]: n.id
Out[8]: UUID('9c485bd2-bb86-4aac-8d20-7cc85abec929')

In [9]: str(n.id)
Out[9]: '9c485bd2-bb86-4aac-8d20-7cc85abec929'
```

This cannot be used because there would be no guarantee that `first` or `last` returns the row i just inserted to the database. This led me to believe that perhaps all i need to do is a simply `obj.refresh_from_db()` call. However this throws a `DoesNotExist` exception.

```
In [12]: from media.models import NewsItem

In [13]: n = NewsItem()

In [14]: n.save()

In [15]: n.id
Out[15]: RandomUUID()

In [16]: n.refresh_from_db()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-735aeb087dd1> in <module>
----> 1 n.refresh_from_db()

~/.var/envs/xkern/vdjango/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in refresh_from_db(self, using, fields)
    635             db_instance_qs = db_instance_qs.only(*fields)
    636
--> 637         db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()
    638         non_loaded_fields = db_instance.get_deferred_fields()
    639         for field in self._meta.concrete_fields:

~/.var/envs/xkern/vdjango/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    433             return clone._result_cache[0]
    434         if not num:
--> 435             raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    436                 "%s matching query does not exist." %
    437                 self.model._meta.object_name

DoesNotExist: NewsItem matching query does not exist.

In [17]:
```

So i went on to try other solutions like trying to explicitly call `model.objects.get(pk=inserted_obj.id)` or `models.objects.filter(pk=inserted_obj.id)`
This does not work either. Here is the issued query for for the latter.

```
In [21]: q = NewsItem.objects.filter(pk=n.id)

In [22]: print(q.query)
SELECT "news_items"."id", "news_items"."title_id", "news_items"."subtitle_id", "news_items"."excerpt_id", "news_items"."text_id", "news_items"."image_id", "news_items"."priority", "news_items"."frequency", "news_items"."text_effects", "news_items"."scroll_speed", "news_items"."scroll_direction", "news_items"."created_at", "news_items"."updated_at" FROM "news_items" WHERE "news_items"."id" = GEN_RANDOM_UUID()

In [23]:
```

That obviously would not work because that generates a new random uuid.

I'm not clear on how to proceed and i have hit a concrete wall at this point. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I think `default=RandomUUID()` has to go in without parenthesis: `default=RandomUUID`

Comment: @MohitC as much as i would like that to be true, i had already tired that. Ideally the model should reflect the reference to the callable as well, but in my desperation to solve the issue i tried to replace the reference to the callable with the actual return value. In the tests i ran this did not cause any issues and UUIDs were being generated on the database side as expected, however nothing changed while trying to access t he primary key after the call to save.